# Preprocess outgoing email bodies with a linux smtp server/proxy?

Tags: linux, smtp, email-server

I have an smtp server running locally on my server, and need to edit the contents of email bodies before they actually get sent out. I have tried using EmailRelay to proxy my smtp server with the --filter option to specify a filter/editing executable, but am getting some odd behavior.

Currently, I specify an executable shell script as the filter program and all it is supposed to do is append some text to a log file and return 0 so I know it actually got called. The weird thing is the email gets sent but nothing shows up in my log file like it should (but it does when I run the script manualy). If I remove the 'exit 0' statement, the email does not send like I would expect.

Are there any other options/suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

[Anubis](http://www.gnu.org/software/anubis/)? A quick look at the available files on milter.org, there's nothing which stands out - but this is specifically the kind of thing milters are supposed to do.

> am getting some odd behavior.

Maybe if you provided more information people might be able to help you sort out what was going wrong with your current setup?